# Transfer reference to list to class

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, reference

I have some problem with references/dereferences.
For example my main func:

```
//some code

std::list<std::string*> strs;
std::string strings = to_string(i);
strs.push_back(strings );
Debugger debug(strs);

main loop
{

i++;
asd = to_string(i);

}
```

And i have Debugger class, that has two functions: constructor and draw.

```
class Debugger
{
private:
    std::list<std::string*> strings;
public:
    Debugger(std::list<std::string*> strs);
    void draw(sf::RenderTarget& rt, int cameraX, int cameraY);
};
```

So i need my debugger always keeps strings up-to-date, because variables changes in main loop.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why is it a list of pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to refer same list (`std::list<std::string*> strs`) from debugger class, you have to pass it by reference.

```
std::list<std::string*> strs;
Debugger debug(strs);     

class Debugger
    {
    public:
        Debugger(std::list<std::string*> &strs);
   };
```

Comment: Ok, my class Debugger class has std::list<std::string*> strings;

Comment: I just need to put strings = strs; in constructor? I want function "draw" use that "strs" through "strings" pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`strs.push_back(&strings )`
as strs stores string pointers